# OpenLayers WFS implementation in java for editing and saving data

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, java

I am  new user in openlayers and want to implement WFS layer to edit and save data to postgis tables.am using netbeans as development environment and m very new in that.Can anyone to help me regarding to this?It would be good if any running example found.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at the tutorial at http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/vector/persist.html. Its based on GeoServer, PostGIS, and OpenLayers. It demonstrates how to add basic editing features to your map.

Answer (score 0):

You could study [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) to see how it uses the [GeoTools library](http://geotools.org) to implement exactly that functionality.